# How I can test from browser (like from swagger) my webapp powered by gRPC-Web without REST?

Tags: swagger, grpc, grpc-web

I want to develop my client-server web app with clear gRPC (gRPC-Web) without REST. Something like described at official doc: https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/web.html

Is it exist any tool like swagger that let me view message formats from .proto and test the server methods by sending any messages from the browser?
I use node.js for server side app

Answer (score 3):

You could use https://kreya.app, which is a gRPC GUI client and supports gRPC-Web. Note that it requires an installation.

*Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of Kreya.*

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. In bloomrpc you have to configure metadata, link, protocol and tls for each request. In kreya there are env settings. Also bloomrpc hasn't got [dark mode](https://github.com/bloomrpc/bloomrpc/pull/182) yet. I hope this functionality stays free in kreya.. Postman and insomnia alas don't know how to do grpc web yet.

Answer (score 1):

The gRPC-Web wire protocol is a binary format and is basically human-unreadable. There is an enhancement request to prettify it https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/317 but we haven't got around to it.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to decode binary format, but I want to have some tool which let me manually enter data in human format (JSON, YAML or simply filling several textbox) and send this data to server in binary. Also I want get deserialized response from server in this tool. I think tool pregenerate message's format and service methods from proto file. In other words I want to have Swagger for gRPC-Web :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with talking to your gRPC backend directly without gRPC web, there are a few CLI and GUI tools for that purpose:

- CLI: The official tool [grpc-cli](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/command_line_tool.md)
- CLI: [grpCurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl)
- GUI: (this requires a golang backend unfortunately): [grpc-json-proxy](https://github.com/jnewmano/grpc-json-proxy)
- GUI: [omgrpc](https://github.com/troylelandshields/omgrpc)

Answer (score -1):

Found this pretty tool for test my gRPC-backend directly (without gRPC-Web): https://github.com/uw-labs/bloomrpc

Comment: This is unrelated to the question. The question regards testing gRPC-Web through client calls which require non-binary testing tools. BloomRPC is specific to gRPC-Web

Comment: @gextra, thanks! I edited my answer. In fact, I did not find exactly the tool that I described in the question